# "Temporary failure resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com" Live USB rescue

Tags: server, apt, kernel, dns, 16.10

I'm trying to rescue my Ubuntu 16.10 server installation, since I have accidentally removed the kernel...

Now that I've booted to a usb, and run a shell with the mounted file-systems, DNS does not seem to want to work, `ping google.com` returns "unknown host"
and if I ping 192.168.1.1 (gateway) it works fine, and if I ping 8.8.8.8 it also works fine, however I cannot do much without DNS.

[image: screen showing APT connection errors]

There is an image of the errors.

So, my question is: how can I restore my DNS so I can ultamately restore my server?

Thanks.

Comment: Alright, I've got it working (sort of) and i can now boot to Ubuntu.
However, it seems my keyboard is not working Nor is ethernet.

Answer (score 3):

Try: `sudo dhclient -v -4`

This should do the trick and fix your connection.

If dhcp does not give you the proper dns server, try to set it manually like this:

`sudo echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf`